# Is Blender crashing because this file is too big?

Tags: import, collada

Context: Noob here. I need to import a .dae file into blender but it weighs 2.22Gb. Suffice it to say, blender crashes when trying to open the file. Activity Monitor app reads an increase in memory pressure coming from blender up to 6.51 Gbs (RAM installed is 8Gb) before it crashes. A decrease in performance of OS is not evident, however, which leads me to believe the file is too big for blender.

I am ready to give up but I wanted to run this by the community before I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your suspicions are correct: the file is just too large for the amount of RAM you have.

To be clear, it's *not* too big for Blender. Blender can handle any size file so long as the OS can give it enough RAM, *quickly enough.* Sometimes there is technically enough RAM available, but the OS can't allocate it quickly enough, so it's not available when Blender needs it. This situation is unlikely for small files, but becomes more and more likely as the amount of RAM you're wanting to allocate at one time increases.

I'd recommend one of two tests, 1) find another system with more RAM to try importing the DAE to see if the problem is with the file's integrity, or its size. 2) If you have access to the original data, export a much smaller subset of the data, and see if that works.

It may be possible to export pieces of the model/scene in smaller files, import them separately into Blender, and then put them back together.

Google Sketchup can apparently import DAE files as well, so you could test importing with that.

Comment: I would say that the standard course of action in these cases is indeed to break the data down into smaller manageable chunks and import them one by one, if you have access to the original data that is. That being said 2.2 GB is A LOT of data, that doesn't even seem right. Even if you were able to import that much data which is unlikely, if you didn't find stability issues while importing you will most likely find them handling that much data in a Blender scene later.

Comment: That's a good point. I hadn't really thought about the size itself. That's a LOT of data. That being said, I've loaded multi-gig point-clouds into Blender before, and it handled them just fine. Part of that is because a single mesh/object is much easier for Blender to handle than many smaller objects, let alone particle systems, physics sims, etc.